# I dont know why i am getting this error with junit

Tags: java, junit

I have the following folder structure

```
base directory = "."
build directory (for classes) = "./build/classes"
build directory (for test classes) = "./build/test/classes"
source = "./src"
test = "./test"
test_libraries = "./test_libraries"
```

everything works fine When I am running the test files with the command

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/junit4-4.11.jar:build/classes:build/test/classes/ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore myclass.MyClassTest
```

but when I change the location of the juint file to `test_libraries/junit4-4.44.jar`
and I run the command

```
java -cp ./test_libraries/junit4-4.11.jar:build/classes:build/test/classes/ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore myclass.MyClassTest
```

I get the following errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:96)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:47)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 18 more
```

Comment: but why then there is no error when I am using /usr/share/java/junit-version?

Comment: How was the /usr/share version installed? I'm guessing whatever method it did a repacked jar with the dependencies in it, while the other you downloaded just junit jar file, and not its dependencies. Look at the classes contained in each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) on your classpath.

Comment: but why then there is no error when I am using /usr/share/java/junit-version?

Comment: It probably sets the classpath programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Hamcrest Jar

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar

JUnit depends on Hamcrest for a lot of methods.

Comment: but why then there is no error when I am using /usr/share/java/junit-version?

Comment: the parts of junit that runs tests requires Hamcrest at runtime.